# Cannot access my dashborad. (Original Parse)

Tags: parse-platform

From 10/21,

1. Push Nortification API always returns an error and we cannot send push notifications from our servers.
2. We can't access our main application dashboard.
3. Campaign push notifications failed for some users.

--

1. API Error Code

   `[2016-10-24 12:19:56] error_trivial.WARNING: [PushNotification] temporary error #0 /var/source/path/to/sdk/parse-php-sdk/src/Parse/ParsePush.php(68): Parse\ParseClient::_request('POST', 'push', NULL, '{"where":{"user...', false) #1`
2. Dash Board

   - Push Notifications page( https://parse.com/apps/xxx/push_notifications )
     :  500 Error
   - Core page( https://parse.com/apps/xxx/collections )
     :  {"code":159,"error":"Temporary error."}